# How to remove/avoid committed files to go to master Branch from remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-stash

I have a  local branch and remote branch(local_stash/new/release1) and master branch(main_stash/new/release1). From my local when i commit changes i am able to see changes on remote branch.

Now how can i move only one file out of these files to master branch. When I am creating merge request from remote to master branch, it is including all checkins. Is there any way we can restriction/remove/avoid the checkins which we don want.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to work with git branch (git branch from your actual point in local master branch), so you create a new local branch for development and you commit into this branch (and revert the local master branch from remote branch, all your changes are on the new local branch so you're not loosing them)

After If you have a commit with this single file you want to move to master, you can run `git cherry-pick <commit id>`

If the file is part of a larger commit, you might need to make a new commit with this single file so you can reference a single commit to be merged on master

Comment: To add color to this answer (which is correct), Git works with commits and merges. Commits represent one or more changed files (generally speaking). If you want to have different files on different branches (for whatever reason), you need a way that either tracks them separately (ie via cherry-picking) or consider additional branches that contain changes you want in multiple other branches that you merge into each periodically.